# Solve following reciprocal system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I'm tryng to solve this following system, I can't find the right idea to solve it
\begin{alignat*}{4}
   x^3 & {}+{} &  y^2 & {}+{}  z{}={}8 \\
    x & {}+{} &  y^3 & {}+{}   z^2 {}={}18 \\
    x^2 & {}+{} & y & {}+{} z^3{}={}30
\end{alignat*}
If we add member to member, and I define $S^n=x^n+y^n+z^n$, we get $S^3+S^2+S=56$, but I don't think it's useful.
The system is symmetric, I've tried multiplying the equations by something in hopes of finding something useful but it didn't work

Comment: Welcome to mathematics stack exchange! I think that Newton's identities can be useful (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)

Comment: I think it should say $S^3+S^2+S=29$, shouldn't it?

Comment: There is no "nice" solution.  Using Mathematica you can eliminate any two of the variables to get a 27th degree polynomial in the remaining one.  But each of these polynomials is irreducible over the integers (i.e., they don't factor).  So there are 27 complex solutions $(x,y,z)$ with no simple way to express any of these triples.

Comment: FYI, of the 27 complex solutions, only one is real:  $(x,y,z) = (1.923, -0.8486, 2.1651)$.  Speaking of Newton, you could use Newton's method to find this solution numerically.

Comment: Given the OP's typos and the mysterious $56$ instead of $29$, I'm betting that the constants are mistyped.  There's probably a replacement for $(10,6,13)$ whose sum is $56$ and makes the system have a nice solution.

Comment: Yeah there is a typo. Sorry me, please. I edited

Answer (score 1):

All complex solutions are given by $y=f(x)$ and $z=g(x)$ for some $f,g\in \Bbb Z[x]$, where $x$ is a root of a (resultant) polynomial equation
$$
x^{27} - 90x^{24} + 3593x^{21} - 36x^{19} - 83345x^{18} - 104x^{17} + 1935
x^{16} + 1237000x^{15} + 4735x^{14} - 42549x^{13} - 12184593x^{12} - 85288x^{11} +
487082x^{10} + 79733324x^9 + 758917x^8 - 3054527x^7 - 334742099x^6 - 3350646
x^5 + 9952068x^4 + 819459392x^3 + 5951210x^2 - 13210074x - 892634387 =0.
$$
The only real root is $x\sim 1.92333428435$.